# Fetch Table data based on multiple timing referred from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in which one has schedules and other table has the availability times. Structure is as follows

```
tbl_schedules

id   Int
userid   Int
schedulefrom   Datetime
scheduletill   Datetime


tbl_useravailability

id
userid
availablefrom
availabletill
```

There can be multiple rows for the user in tbl_useravailability for the same day. That is the user can be available from `2014:10:17 05:00:00 to  2014:10:17 12:00:00,  2014:10:17 15:00:00 to  2014:10:17 18:00:00,  2014:10:17 19:00:00 to  2014:10:17 23:00:00`

The challenge is to pick the schedules for other users from the schedule table on the given availability day something like `where userid <> 1;`

Comment: I'm not sure if I get this right, but can't you solve it with BETWEEN?

Comment: No Michael.. we will have multiple rows in tbl_useravailability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link and effort spend to resolve this. I have made some modifications in your query and got this worked. Thanks

```
SELECT
    S.id AS scheduleid,
    S.userid,
    S.schedulefrom,
    S.scheduletill,
    UA.id AS availabilityid,
    UA.availablefrom,
    UA.availabletill
FROM
    tbl_schedules AS S
JOIN tbl_useravailability AS UA
    ON S.schedulefrom between  UA.availablefrom and UA.availabletill

WHERE
    UA.userid=1 and s.userid <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following (view sample at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f94e6/1/0):

```
SELECT
    S.id AS scheduleid,
    S.userid,
    S.schedulefrom,
    S.scheduletill,
    UA.id AS availabilityid,
    UA.availablefrom,
    UA.availabletill
FROM
    tbl_schedules AS S
JOIN tbl_useravailability AS UA
    ON  S.userid = UA.userid
    AND S.schedulefrom >= UA.availablefrom
    AND S.scheduletill <= UA.availabletill
WHERE
    S.userid <> 1
```

This will show you all users whose availability is within their schedule periods.